# nginx reverse proxy with cache and gzip_static on

Tags: caching, nginx, proxy, lua

I need help to setup nginx reverse with gzip_statice to serve precompressed gzipped content to browser with gzip header request where the backend does not support gzip_static

I understand the vhost block for nginx but what I need help is when browser request for a file https://www.domain.dom/file.txt the nginx reverse proxy with cache and gzip_static enabled  pulls the file.txt.gz ( with gz extension instead of non gz ) and serves the browser as file.txt .

I am able to achieve this with backend where backend is on nginx and has "gzip_static on" enabled  but what I need help for is where the  backend does not have nginx and gzip_static on, in this scenario I want my reverse proxy to pull the gzipped file from backend with gz extension when browser header has Content-Encoding: gzip instead of asking backed for file name which just came and same time cache it for future request of same .

One option I can think of is  to use curl with lua in nginx block to pull the file to locally on reverse proxy and serve that,  but it is not what I am looking for as I dont want want reverse proxy to serve  static file locally from its own directories instead works with standard caching mechanism.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?